# Loading scripts from index.html Vs Node Package install

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am newbie to angular2, so far I know 2 ways of adding external css/js into app.

1. Directly in `index.html`

   - Could be a CDN or local file.
2. Installing the external npm package using the `npm install <package-name>`

   - Note: Works only if the package is available in NPM

I am trying to use an external js which is not available in NPM as of now. So, will be adding it in `index.html`

Now, this is a two part question.

1. Does adding external links in `index.html` reduces the build time(anyway it's already super fast) in `angular build --prod --aot`?
2. By using any of the two ways of adding external js/css files, will there be any performance impact in browser while using the app or it has no impact on performance?

Comment: Is it a node package? And maybe on GitHub? You could install it from Github. Using `npm install https://github.com/<GITHUB_USER>/<GITHUB-PROJECT>/tarball/<BRANCH>`

Comment: Also adding js to the index.html might help your general build-time and your package might be smaller, but it won't use any bundling. The ng-cli is doing this quite nicely and is also removing dead code.

Comment: Yes, it is available on Github.

Comment: This way you might be able to install it. I've two dependencies in my project, which are imported over GitHub. ...important is that the dependency has a `package.json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to recap what I already said in the comments.

Adding the JS file into the `index.html` may reduce your build time, but it will exclude it from being watch by *WebPack*. *WebPack* is bundling you files and also removed dead code or sorts out duplicated dependencies. So there is a definite advantage of importing it as node package using the `npm install`

But sometimes this is just not possible. Then you need to add it to your index.html, but you won't have any advantage out of this.

If your package is **not** on *npm* but on GitHub then you can easily install it from GitHub. Here a small example using the [jQuery](https://github.com/jquery/jquery) repo:

```
npm install https://github.com/jquery/jquery/tarball/master --save
```

Important is that you use **tarball** instead of **tree**. This will install jQuery in you application.